# Facebook: FQL for fetching all posts on a managed page throws one of two exceptions

Tags: facebook-fql, restfb

I am using the RestFB client to fetch all post_ids of a Facebook Page.

The query is

```
select post_id from stream where source_id=265813166783408
```

Where the id if of the page I'm querying. It can be found [here](http://www.facebook.com/pages/Rowz/265813166783408)

I initially tried executing this without an access token. This gives a **104: Requires valid signature** error from Facebook.

I looked up this error and the solution that many gave on SO is to use an access token. However if I try with an accessToken (with permissions: manage_pages, publish_stream, read_stream, offline_access, read_insights) then Facebook gives a different error **190: Impersonated access tokens can only be used with the Graph API**.

Does this mean I shouldn't use FQL for getting page posts. The Facebook documentation doesn't mention anything on these lines but like I said it keeps alternating between these two errors.

PS: I can use the Graph API with my access token to fetch Posts but for my specific scenario I felt FQL would be a far better option, since I can nest this query into a query on the comments table (eventual aim).

Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

Please see Facebook developers for a discussion on [this particular issue](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/416084548430182?ref=notif&notif_t=open_graph_comment) If you are using the RestFB library then also see the [relevant issue](https://github.com/revetkn/restfb/issues/34)

Comment: Have you found anything on this matter. I have the same problem when making a request using fql and page access_token? Is there a work around.

Comment: @NimmoNet - None so far. I am using Graph API to fetch Posts and then switching to FQL for comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We encountered the same problem and found it to be an issue with using fbclient library and a page access token.  We switched to calling the API directly (with the Apache HttpClient) and our FQL ran fine with the page access tokens.

Comment: Oh is that the case? I will try this out and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: The RestFB library that I am using currently uses the deprecated endpoint for read only queries. The current unreleased library has a new function to handle this issue so am currently maintaining a local workaround. You were on the right track so I will accept your answer :)